# Metadata in dvi files

Tags: pdf, dvi

I found out that even when creating dvi files, e.g. with `pdflatex --output-format=dvi ...`
one can use `hyperref`.
When i use just `\usepackage{hyperref}`, then my viewer `okular` shows some content.
On the other hand there is no link clickable.
When I convert my dvi file into pdf with `dvipdfm`,
then the content becomes clickable.
So it must have been present before!

My questions are:
I always thought dvi is a format just drawing fonts and lines, but seems not true.
What kind of information is in dvi files?
Is there a reference? a specification?

Also I suspect that i must configure `hyperref` if using it in the context

Comment: a `\special` node in  dvi consists of essentially arbitrary text which is interpreted by the dvi driver, so specials targetting dvipdfm do not work for dvips or dvisvgm etc, this is how color, graphics, scaling, plotting, linking, ... all  work `\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}`  so hyperref uses dvipdfm specials (unless you are using xetex in which case (x)dvipdfm(x) is assumed.

Comment: Not replying, but do you know about `xdvi`? If you are on unixen, best way to view dvi files.  (on macos works under XQuartz)

Comment: @david carlisle: Ineresting. By the way, difficult to find a specification on dvi

Comment: @user69... Hm "knowing" is too much said. I know about the existence of xdv, written by xelatex. But I have no idea whats the difference, only that there is no mime type and my viewer does not view it.

Comment: `texdoc dvitype` has a reasonable description of the format

Comment: xdvi is unrelated to xdv. the first is dvi viewer for X-windows.  latter is eXtended dvi as written by xetex (with some extra opcodes to handle  opentype fonts)

Comment: ah, i mixed up. true.

Comment: thank you for texdoc

Answer (score 2):

A `\special` node in dvi consists of essentially arbitrary text which is interpreted by the dvi driver, so specials targetting dvipdfm do not work for dvips or dvisvgm etc.

This is how color, graphics, scaling, plotting, linking, ... all work

latex packages will assume `dvips` specials if used with latex, and
(x)dvipdfm(x) specials if used with xelatex. (lualatex and pdflatex have similar primitives that directly access the pdf back end writing)

So to use `dvipdfm` with latex you need option such as

`\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}`

so hyperref uses dvipdfm specials.

`texdoc dvitype` has a description of the dvi format. `dvitype` or the newer `dviasm` may be used to see a human readable output of the dvi structure. `dviasm`  can also handle the extended `.xdv` dvi files written by xetex.